# CannedClassifier at Tensorflow Lattice with more than 2 classes

Tags: tensorflow, classification, lattice

could someone helps me with tensorflow lattice? here's my problem: I want to classify one label with 18 features. if I use a label with two classes (e.g. 0 and 1) everything is fine. but my label has 30 classes and I get an error-message, that only one label is allowed (I use only one label and if I use the same structure of the DLN with a label with two classes I don't get these error-message). has anyone experience with that? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow lattice is not the best tool for classification problems. It's most commonly used for regression problems where you want to enforce monothonicity constraints. That's probably the reason why it does not allow more than one label.

It would be helpful if you could explain why you want to use tensorflow lattice here in particular. Maybe it's possible to just use a neural net instead?

Comment: "It would be helpful if..." this should be in the comment section